# writing a blog and using file i/o input by newest date first?

Tags: php

```
<?php

foreach (glob("POSTS/*.txt") as $filename) 
        {       

            $file = fopen($filename, 'r') or exit("Unable to open file!");
            //Output a line of the file until the end is reached


                echo date('D, M jS, Y H:i a', filemtime($filename))."<br>";
                echo '<h2>' . htmlspecialchars(fgets($file)) . '</h2>';

                while(!feof($file))
                  {
                  echo fgets($file). "<br>";
                  }
            echo "<hr/>";
        }
    fclose($file);



    ?>
```

Im writing a blog and have been able to input the files but only by the oldest file first

how do i make it so that i input them by the newest date first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to put the file array in the right order (date desc).

```
function timeSort($first, $second) {
    $firsttime = filemtime($first);
    $secondtime = filemtime($second);

    return $secondtime - $firsttime;
}

$files = glob("POSTS/*.txt");

usort($files, 'timeSort');

foreach ($files as $filename) {

     /* Same as before */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on using text files instead of a database to store your blog entries, one easy way to sort them in the desired way would be to use [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), like the following:

```
$posts = array_reverse(glob("POSTS/*.txt"));
foreach($posts as $filename) {
    // do your stuff
}
```